# Catch specific exceptions and do same stuff under all of them?

Tags: java, exception

I see below code in my legacy project where i am catching different types of exception and intention is just to logg them

```
        try {
         //somecode
        }
        catch (ProjectExceptionException1 e) {
          log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        catch (ProjectExceptionException2 e) {
          log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
         catch (Exception e) {
          log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

My point is if requirement is just to log the exception(whether its checked or unchecked), above code should be replaced by below one
that makes code simple and more readable.  As per my understanding there is not point of catching specific exception and doing
same stuff under all. Is n't it? Let me know if i am missing something here.

```
    try {
         //somecode
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

**UPDATE:-** even if are throwing specific exception on UI just to display the stack trace like below. Even then it does not make sense
.Basically if we want to handle the specific exception in special way then it would make sense. Right?

```
try {
             //somecode
            }
            catch (ProjectExceptionException1 e1) {
              throw e1;
            }
            catch (ProjectExceptionException2 e2) {
              throw e2;
            }
             catch (Exception e3) {
              throw e3;
            }
```

Comment: If you're just logging, then do what you are proposing in your second snippet.

Comment: @merlin2011 is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly fine to replace the top block with the single `catch (Exception e)`, as long as you are only logging and do not need any `Exception`-specific handling.

Answer (score 0):

As of [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) you can `catch` multiple exceptions and handle them all in the same way using the syntax:

```
catch (ProjectExceptionException1 | ProjectExceptionException2 ex)
```

So, if you want to log some exceptions but act on others, you could group the behaviours in this manner, assuming that the actions you would like to perform are the same. e.g. print stack trace then log for `ProjectExceptionException1` and `ProjectExceptionException2`, but only log for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade the code to java 1.7, you could use the new multi-catch feature. It could look like this:

```
    try {
     //somecode
    }
    catch (ProjectExceptionException1 | ProjectExceptionException2 e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

You may want to reconsider catching Exception and only catching exceptions that you know would be thrown by the code in the try block so you don't just resort to logging unexpected exceptions.
Here's a link that goes into more detail about the feature with examples: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java7exceptions-486908.html